# AccessDeniedExceptionnull (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 403 Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have issues pushing to amplify after adding resource same problem, after adding auth with
amplify add auth
amplify push
I get

```
Following resources failed

Resource Name: UserPoolClientLambda (AWS::Lambda::Function)
Event Type: create
Reason: AccessDeniedExceptionnull (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 8434d2a2-4287-4b79-b22f-5d95094436a0; Proxy: null)


× An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud

Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete
An error occurred during the push operation: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete
```

How I resolve this ?

PS: amplify cli is version 4.41.2

Comment: It looks like there a similar open issue on the Amplify CLI GitHub repository. Please follow https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/5982.

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to figure it out.
My issue has something to do with my exposed api key case with my users.

I had help from the AWS support. Initially, I was just going to fix my billing payment method, and they mentioned that they locked my account due to the exposed api key. They walked me through it to rotate my API key and I just waited around 3-5 hours to get my account unlocked.

I tried it after following the same steps and it worked

```
$ amplify add auth
$ amplify push
```